# How to select second image of every div?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the second image inside the div. My structure is like

```
<div class='test'>

   <a href='#'>   <img src='haha.jpg'/>   </a>
   <a href='#'>   <img src='imageINeed.jpg'/>  </a>

</div>

<div class='test'>

   <a href='#'>   <img src='haha.jpg'/>   </a>
   <a href='#'>   <img src='imageINeed1.jpg'/>  </a>

</div>

<div class='test'>

   <a href='#'>   <img src='haha.jpg'/>   </a>
   <a href='#'>   <img src='imageINeed2.jpg'/>  </a>

</div>
```

My jquery below won't work

```
  $('.test').find('img:last').each(function(){

         $(this).css('max-width','none').width(500);
   })
```

I want to select the second image inside every `test` div. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
$(".test").each(function () {
    $(this).find("img:eq(2)");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your images are inside anchors, you need to select the second anchor and then it's child image:

```
$('.test a:nth-child(2) img').each(...)
```